# How do I mock any arguments to a private method using PowerMockito?

Tags: methods, junit, mockito, private, powermock

I’m using Mockito 1.9.5, PowerMock 1.5.1, JUnit 4.11, and Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE.  I’m trying to write a JUnit test in which I want to mock a private method doing nothing.  The private method signature is

```
public class MyService
{

    …
    private void myMethod(byte[] data, UserFile userFile, User user)
    {
```

And in my JUnit test I have

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
@PrepareForTest(MyServiceImpl.class)
public class MyServiceIT 
{

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Autowired
    private MyService m_mySvc;
    private MyService m_mySvcSpy;

    @Before
    public final void setup() throws Exception
    {
        m_mySvcSpy = PowerMockito.spy(m_mySvc);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(m_mySvcSpy, “myMethod”, Matchers.any(byte[].class), Matchers.any(UserFile.class), Matchers.any(User.class));
```

Unfortunately, the second line dies with the exception

```
testUploadFile(org.mainco.subco.user.service.MyServiceIT)  Time elapsed: 12.693 sec  <<< ERROR!
```

org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name ‘myMethod’ with parameter types: [ null, null, null ] in class org.mainco.subco.user.service.UserFileService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$4e52bc77.
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.throwExceptionIfMethodWasNotFound(WhiteboxImpl.java:1247)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:985)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:882)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:713)
        at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
        at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:93)
        at org.mainco.subco.user.service.MyServiceIT.setup(UserFileServiceIT.java:42)

What is the right way to mock generic arguments for a private method using PowerMockito?

Comment: I don't understand why the PowerMockito.doNothing().when(m_mySvcSpy, "myMethod", null, null, null); line is there at all. What is it supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and used "suppress" ...

```
suppress(method(MyServiceImpl.class,  “myMethod”));
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but I believe the reason the private method isn't found is that it *doesn't exist* in the object provided by Spring for the `MyService` interface. This object is a *proxy*  , an instance of a generated class which does not extend `MyServiceImpl`; so, there is no `private myMethod(...)` in it.

To avoid the problem, the test should simply not use Spring. Instead, instantiate `MyServiceImpl` directly in the `setup()` method. If the test needs other dependencies to get injected into `m_mySvc`, then create mocks for those and let PowerMock inject them.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted the private method to "return" something, so this is what I did

```
        MyTestClass spyInstance = spy(MyTestClass.getNewInstance());
        MyGenericClass obj = mock(MyGenericClass.class);

           doReturn(obj).when(spyInstance,method(MyTestClass.class,"privateMethod",
            String.class,HashMap.class,Class.class)).
            withArguments("624",null,MyGenericClass.class);`
```

where my private method is ...

```
private <T> T privateMethod(String str,HashMap<String,String> map,Class<T> c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your test is annotated with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. In this case you have to use the [`PowerMockRule`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule):

```
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    ...
```

Moreover your are stubbing a method of `MyService` with powermock. So you must annotate the test class with [`@PrepareForTest`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html):

```
...
@PrepareForTest(MyServiceImpl.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    ...
```

---

Complete code:

```
@PrepareForTest(MyServiceImpl.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    private MyService spy;

    @Before
    public final void setup() throws Exception {
        spy = PowerMockito.spy(service);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(spy,
                "myMethod",
                Matchers.any(byte[].class),
                Matchers.any(UserFile.class),
                Matchers.any(User.class));
    }

    ...
}
```

You could see [a full example of spying in the documentation.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#A_full_example_of_spying)

Comment: I updated my code to reflect your suggestions.  However, I still get the same exception as above, occuring on your first "doNothing" call (the line after spy = ).  Not sure if this matters but "MyService.class" is an interface.  The implementing class "MyServiceImpl.class" actually contains the private method.

Comment: I remove the second `doNothing`, it was an error. It is really important to know that `MyService` is an interface.

Comment: You will have to use `@PrepareForTest(MyServiceImpl.class)`.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer to reflect your code, but running that still produces the same exception, "org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name 'myMethod' with parameter types"

Comment: doNothing must be called with MyServiceImpl.

Comment: Did you make any changes to your code above?  It looks the same given your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The premise for your question seems to imply that you're violating the [Single Responsibility Principle  (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); if you need to test the private method, and to do that you need to inject stuff into it, you should probably consider moving it out to a different service.

I suggest that you do the following:

```
public class MyService implements IService { // I know it's not a strong convention in
                                             // the Java world, but I'm primarily a C#
                                             // guy, so I tend to give any interface a
                                             // name that starts with captital "I"

    public MyService(IDependencyOne dep1, IDependencyTwo dep2) {
        // ...
    }

    public Stuff getTheStuffThatAnIServiceGets() {
        // your previously private method was used here before
        // Now, it's instead a method defined on the IDependencyTwo interface,
        // so you have it available as _dep2.myMethod(...)
    }
}

public class OtherService implements IDependencyTwo {
    public void myMethod(/* possibly some arguments... */) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

With this separation, you can inject something that mocks the behavior of the previously private method (just mock `IDependencyTwo`) when you're testing `MyService`, and similarly you can mock whatever you need to inject into the previously private method by mocking and injecting the dependencies of `IDependencyTwo`.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, it is not an option to move the private method out of the implementing class at this time.  Given that, how would I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are seeing this exception:

`org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found with name ‘myMethod’ with parameter types: [ null, null, null ] in class`

Can you try using mockito's [isNull](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isNull%28java.lang.Class%29) matcher (and probably with some type-casting)?

In other words, you use instead

`PowerMockito.doNothing().when(m_mySvcSpy, "myMethod", Matchers.isNull(byte[].class), Matchers.isNull(UserFile.class), Matchers.isNull(User.class));`

Btw, you can [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4) `Matchers.isNull` so that you can simply use `isNull` instead of `Matchers.isNull`

Comment: The arguments I'm passing into the method are not null, though.

Comment: Hmm, can you post the your unit test code? The exception looks that you are passing in null in some unit test.

Comment: The code is tehre in all its glory.  It is not even getting past the @Before (setup) method, dying on the line where I invoke "Powermock.doNothing()..."

Comment: I have some POC coding showing the `byte[] data` param can be mocked correctly, which suggests that the cause might be related to your `org.mainco.subco.user.service.UserFileService`. Can you explain what `UserFile` and `User` have?

Comment: Another thing you can try (in case you haven't) is to debug your unit test and step into the offending code.